# Event messageCreate not firing/emitting when I send a DM to my bot (discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made this code for logging the DMs that are sent to my bot:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const attachment = message.attachments.first()

    if (message.channel.type === 'DM') {
        console.log(message.content)

        const dmLogEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle(`${message.author.tag} dmed the bot and said: `)
            .setDescription(message.content)
            .setFooter(`User's id: ${message.author.id}`)

        if (message.attachments.size !== 0) {
            dmLogEmbed.setImage(attachment.url)

        }

        client.channels.fetch("852220016249798756").then((channel) => {

            channel.send({ embeds: [dmLogEmbed] })

        })
    }

});
```

But when updating to discord.js v13 it didn't work anymore, for what I understood the only change is that the 'dm' channel type isn't 'dm' anymore but 'DM', so I changed it in my code, but it is still not working and I don't really know why.

Comment: What have you debugged? Confirm that your `messageCreate` event is emitting and check whether or not the if statement checks out

Comment: I have successfully reproduced your problem and have no clue why it happens. I thought that it was because you were missing an intent `DIRECT_MESSAGES`. I added that but still nothing... The `messageCreate` is not firing entirely... (works in guilds tho)

Comment: Yeah i also think that the problem is in the event, maybe the way dms emits these types of events changed but i'm not sure, i also have no clue

Comment: Got it somehow working, but I am not sure if it is what you wanted. The bot has to send at least one DM to the user first. Then the `messageCreate` is firing as usual. Not sure if there is some way around that. I'm gonna look into it.

Comment: I have written a complete solution to your problem in my answer, you can check that out.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Make sure you have `DIRECT_MESSAGES` in your client's intents.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"] });
```

There is a breaking change in the Discord API v8. For reference see [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#dm-channels).

> On Discord API v8 and later, DM Channels do not emit the `CHANNEL_CREATE` event, which means discord.js is unable to cache them automatically. In order for your bot to receive DMs, the `CHANNEL` partial must be enabled.

So we need to enable the partial `CHANNEL` as well. Keep in mind that when dealing with [partial data](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html), you often want to **fetch** the data, because it is not complete. However this doesn't seem to be your case, if you are using the `messageCreate` event. The `message` received is not partial nor `message.channel`. To check if something is partial, you can use the `.partial` property. For example [`Message.partial`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=partial) or [`Channel.partial`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=partial).

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"], partials: ["CHANNEL"] });
```

Now it should work as good old discord.js v12.