# I am trying to code a discord bot that shows the status of my minecraft server but The bot isn't responding to the command not even with an error

Tags: javascript, discord.js, minecraft

```
const {Client, RichEmbed, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

 
const bot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
 
 
const token = 'token is a secret';
 
const PREFIX = '!';
 
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot has come online.');
});
 
bot.on('messageCreate', message =>{
 
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
 
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'mc':
            ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
 
 
            ping = ('ip', port, (error, reponse) =>{
                if(error) throw error
                const Embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setTitle('Server Status')
                .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)
                
                message.reply({ embeds: [Embed] });
            })
        break
 
    }
 
    })
 
bot.login(token);
```

Niether is it showing any error. Its just not responding when the command is being issued. Please tell whats wrong with my code.. and please tell how I can correct it. in the line, "`bot.on('messageCreate', message =>{...`" if i am replacing `'messageCreate'` with `'message'`, the bot is responding on issuing the command, but with an error message saying ' `(node:25372) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead`'. Please help me :(

Some replies to this question suggested me to replace the line " `ping = ('ip', port, (error, reponse) =>{`" with "`ping('ip', port, error, response) =>{`" but then it gives the error `ping is not a function`.  On some suggestions i realised that "`RichEmbed()`" was removed in discord v12, so i tried replacing the line `const Embed = new RichEmbed()` with `const Embed = new MessageEmbed()` but unfortunately that also did not help. Yet the bot did not respond when the command was issued. The thing is, it also does not show any error message, so i am not able to catch where i have gone wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event messageCreate not firing/emitting when I send a DM to my bot (discord.js v13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700270/event-messagecreate-not-firing-emitting-when-i-send-a-dm-to-my-bot-discord-js-v)

Comment: Also, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68989068/10952503) can help you

Comment: @Elikill58 I don't think they are using DM

Comment: Why are you using `new RichEmbed()`? That was removed in v12

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line

```js
            ping = ('ip', port, (error, reponse) =>{
```

and replacing it with

```js
            ping('ip', port, (error, reponse) =>{
```

The first one is setting a variable `ping` to be two strings `'ip'` and `port` and a third one who is a function `(error,response) =>{}`, the second one is using the `ping` function to actually do something on your code