# Trying to code a discord bot that shows the status of my minecraft server but the bot isn't responding to the command not even with an error

Tags: javascript, discord.js, minecraft

```
const {Client, RichEmbed, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js'); 

 
const bot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
 
 
const token = 'token is a secret';
 
const PREFIX = '!';
 
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot has come online.');
});
 
bot.on('messageCreate', message =>{
 
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
 
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'mc':
            
            const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
 
 
            ping.status('ip', { port: port})
             .then((response)=>{
                
                const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Server Status', )
                .addField('Server IP', response.host)
                .addField('Server Version', response.version)
                .addField('Online Players', response.onlinePlayers)
                .addField('Max Players', response.maxPlayers)
                
                message.channel.send({ embeds: [Embed] });
            })
            .catch((error)=>{console.error(error);});
        break
 
    }
 
    })
 
bot.login(token);
```

I am coding a discord bot that sends the status of my minecraft server when the assigned command is issued. But for some reason it is not able to create the embed. This is the error i am getting: `RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.` Please tell me where i have gone wrong and how should i correct it.

Comment: Looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-server-util, `ping = ('ip...` and `ping = require...` aren't the proper usage. As you are redeclaring the variable ping, and are not assigning it as a variable. Instead, I recommend setting ping as a constant when importing; `const ping = require(...`and using a command such as ping. Using the `ping.status('ip', ...)` or otherwise to fetch the data instead.

Comment: Please don't create multiple question. Try to comment on answer an reply to other comment to fix your issue, or [edit] your question but don't create multiple of them

Comment: Solution provided in their alternative question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69668331/13785528