# Discord.js not sending message nor giving an error

Tags: node.js, discord.js

My discord.js version is v13, and it's not sending a message, nor is it giving an error in the console so that I can try to figure out what is wrong with it.

The code itself is over 4000 lines of code, so I tried putting it in a separate script to only test one function (which is the ping function), yet still nothing.

If you ask, this the `async` is only apart of another function in the main script where I use `await` a lot.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ 'DIRECT_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGES' ] });
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Main script ready! Currently in ${client.guilds.size} servers!`);
  client.user.setActivity("Using a test script");

});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
  if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;

  if(command === "ping") {
    const m = await message.channel.send("Loading...")
    m.edit(`Pong! ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`)
  }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Please include the message you are sending.

Comment: Can you try this `const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"], partials: ["CHANNEL"] });`? 

Took it from here, detailed explanation is in the answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68701051/18312559

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! I am trying to upgrade from V11 straight to V13 so that's the problem I was having.

Comment: Glad I could help ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS.

Change:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ 'DIRECT_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGES' ] });
```

to

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ 'GUILDS', 'DIRECT_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGES' ] });
```